# How to fetch response with Regex?

Tags: regex, scala, gatling

This is the part of response of Login request (its in index.jsp) from where I have to fetch `current_account_id` and `current_workspace_id`

```
var parameters = 'objectId=&type=Desktop&dashboardType=desktop_events&forceReplace=true' +
    '&current_account_id=505520&current_workspace_id=505519' +
    '&skipAccountCheck=&skipWorkspaceCheck=';
    var refreshRequest = registerForAutoRefresh('desktop_events_panel', 'desktop_events_panel', 'eventDataController', 'viewevents', parameters, recentActivityHandler);
    refreshRequest.doRequest();
```

I want to fetch value of 'current_account_id' and 'current_workspace_id'

I have used below code in my Gatling script to fetch the value. but no luck

```
http("request_7")
            .get("/desktop/dashboard/index.jsp")
            .check(regex("""current_account_id=(\d+)""").saveAs("accountID"))
            .check(regex("""current_workspace_id=(\d+)""").saveAs("workspaceID"))
            .headers(headers_6)
```

Error:

> Request: request_7: KO regex(current_account_id=(\d+)).find(0).exists,
>   found nothing

any idea how to fetch the value?